# Call a module containing command line arguments from another module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Consider a following python files, is there any way to pass `cl arguments` toother module on import? (calling `os.system` is not desired)

```
# A.py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # -- resolve command line arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--name', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--out_file', type=str, required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # -- do some operations
    # -- save results in `out_file`


#B.py
import A
# how to pass `name` and `out_file` in main?
```

Comment: `import A` won't execute the code in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, so there's no point passing arguments. It looks like you want to *run* `A.py`, not *import* it.

Comment: Oh. you are right. Is there any workaround for this situation?

Comment: [What is the best way to call a script from another script?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1186789)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is of course to change A.py to have a `main` function taking arguments as parameters as you were suggested in other answers.

So you really should use:

A.py:

```
# A.py
def main(args):
    # -- resolve command line arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--name', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--out_file', type=str, required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args(args)

    # -- do some operations
    # -- save results in `out_file`

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

B.py:

```
import A
import sys

A.main([sys.argv[0], '--name', 'NAME_X', '--out_file', 'FILE.YY'])
```

That being said, `sys.argv` is mutable, so it is possible to change it before calling `ArgumentParser.parse_args`.

So this is possible (even if a bit more *hacky*):

A.py:

```
# A.py
def main():
    # -- resolve command line arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--name', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--out_file', type=str, required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()                # always use sys.argv

    # -- do some operations
    # -- save results in `out_file`

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

B.py:

```
import A
import sys

sys.argv = [sys.argv[0], '--name', 'NAME_X', '--out_file', 'FILE.YY'])
A.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# A.py
def main():
    # -- resolve command line arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--name', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--out_file', type=str, required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # -- do some operations
    # -- save results in `out_file`
    return out_file

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()

#B.py
import A
def main():
    out_file = A.main()
# how to pass `name` and `out_file` in main?
```

Answer (score 1):

In `a.py` you need to move the `main` stuff to a function, for example a `def main()`. I also added an `arguments=None` parameter to `main()` that receives the args from `b.py`.

```
# a.py
import argparse

def main(arguments=None):
    # -- resolve command line arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--name', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--out_file', type=str, required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args(arguments)

    # -- do some operations
    # -- save results in `out_file`

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And then you can pass arguments to that function in `b.py` like so

```
#b.py
from a import main

main(['--name', 'some_name', '--out_file', 'file.txt'])
```